# Struts 2 file upload and save

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, openshift

I have successfully uploaded a file in Struts2 with the following code:

```
String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF\\files\\";
            fileToCreate = new File(filePath, getUserDocFileName());

            FileUtils.copyFile(this.userDoc, fileToCreate);
```

The problem is that the file gets copied to the \build\web\WEB-INF\files folder. Now, when I try to retrieve the file using result type stream:

```
String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF\\files\\";
File file = new File(filePath + getFileName());
            try {
                inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



<action name="loadFile" class="com.app.Controller" method="loadFile">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">${fileType}</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename="${fileName}"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </action>
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action.
```

Any help regarding this problem?

Is `FileUtils.copyFile` approach same as setting `struts.multipart.saveDir` property?

How can I place the file in the WEB-INF folder but not in the build folder?

The files should not get deleted whenever I build my project again. I want to deploy it to OpenShift later on.

Comment: Could you specify another location other than `WEB-INF`?

Comment: @RomanC I want the files NOT to be accessible from anywhere. That is why I have kept them under WEB-INF. If the files can be secure outside, then I'll do that

Comment: I think you are mistaken, it's accessible from anywhere with file access rights but protected from your application to access it.

Comment: @RomanC I mean no one will be able to access the file through their browser like http://app.com/WEB-INF/file.doc

Comment: The same is applied to you when you use `File`.

Comment: @RomanC Is there a work around? Or I have to place my files outside WEB-INF?

Comment: You are probably missing getter/setter for `inputStream` and/or not using `java.io.InputStream` class.

Comment: @AleksandrM there is getter/setter for the inputStream. The problem is in using it with OpenShift as it can't access the file

Comment: In that case you should get a different exception, shouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, now I get FileNotFoundException. It runs on localhost. But on Openshift I think I have to use the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it from servlet context

```
InputStream is = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/files/" + fileName);
```

Comment: How will I set the ${fileType} and ${fileName}?

Comment: create getter and setter for properties `contentType` and `fileName`, is this struts2 fileupload or servlet?

Comment: Don't mind this is file download, I've just figured out that they are dynamic parameters of the result, the getter required. It's not EL expression.

Comment: You should name it filedownload because you are not uploading, fileupload works different.

Comment: Yes but how do I get the File object from InputStream? Should I recreate the file? I will need the File object for fileName and contentType as these parameters will change according to the file

Comment: Don't you have `File` object, fileName, and contentType when you uploaded a file? You could keep a record this info, the fileName you know the content type you may construct yourself like "application/octet-stream".

Comment: I have implemented your code. It seems to work on localhost as before. But on OpenShift, I get the same error.